# Jsoup return specific values within href

Tags: jsoup

I have some html that I need to extract values from and I can't figure out how to get at it using jsoup.  Below is a snippet of what was extracted.  I'm anticipating have more than just one Element to iterate through and extract:

```
<a href="javascript:runReport('R_195','/action/reports/project/costing/periodic/summary/report');">
```

What I need to retrieve is contained inside the parenthesis and the values inside the single quotes.

For example, my expected result for my first pass is returning R_195

my second pass will be /action/reports/project/costing/periodic/summary/report

How can I use jsoup to consistently get what is contained in the first set of '' and the second set of ''?  Seems simple but I've been scratching my head trying to figure this out.  new to jsoup and java!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's nice when you can figure it out yourself.  All I really needed was to insert a little java.  Mind was stuck in jsoup and I forgot that all I'm dealing with is a bunch of strings!  Below is my code for anyone else that may hit a wall like I did...

```
// Get the reportID and address from the href text
int r = 0;
for(Element telemetryReport : telemetryReports) {
    String reportID = telemetryReport.attr("href").toString();
    reportID = reportID.substring(reportID.indexOf("'")+1);
    reportID = reportID.substring(0, reportID.indexOf("'"));
    unanetReportIDArray[r]=reportID;

    // Get the address
    String reportAddress = telemetryReport.attr("href").toString();
    reportAddress = reportAddress.substring(reportAddress.indexOf("','")+3);
    reportAddress = reportAddress.substring(0, reportAddress.indexOf("');"));
    unanetAddressArray[r]=reportAddress;
    System.out.println(unanetAddressArray[r]);
    }
```